# formcontrol setValue does not trigger errors

Tags: angular

I'm setting the value of a angular form control. I want to raise required: true error while setting empty string after removing trailing empty spaces, but it's not raising the error.

```
form.get('name').setValue(form.get('name').value.trim()
```

Please not the value of the 'name' is empty string example "  "

I'm expecting the required error to be raised and highlight the form control.

Comment: did u trie to use `patchValue` instead?

Comment: yes, same result. it is not raising the error.

Comment: Please add to your question where you've declared the form and its form controls and their validators, this will help us answer the question better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [updateValueAndValidity()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity) method on your FormControl, after you've set its value. Also try to call this method on your FormGroup.

Comment: it does not helped as well.